# Why are Object.keys() and for ... in different?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a bit of browser object discovery, figuring out browser built-ins etc...

I noticed different results when trying to get at the window object's properties (just FYI I'm using Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit)).

```
Object.keys(window).length;
```

returns 7 keys. From the docs Object.keys() returns the enumerable properties of an object.

But the docs also say that `for ... in` iterates over the enumerable properties of an object. However:

```
    var i = 0;
    for (var propertyName in window) {
        i++;
    }
```

returns a count of 177.

Why is this different? Shouldn't they both only be returning the count of enumerable properties?

Comment: `for..in` loops the prototype too, `Object.keys` only own properties.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`for-in`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) loops over the object's own enumerable properties **and** the enumerable properties of its prototype (and *its* prototype, etc.). [`Object.keys`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) only lists the object's **own** enumerable properties.

So `Object.keys` builds an array *something* like this:

```
var keys = [];
var key;
for (key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // But using an internal, non-overrideable
                                      // operation, not literally the method
        keys.push(key);
    }
}
```

Note the `hasOwnProperty` check (it's not really a call to the method, it's an internal check that can't be tricked by replacing the method or similar).