# for..in or for..of Object keys

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, for-in-loop, for-of-loop

So my IDE doesn't like when I use a for..in loop to iterate over an object keys. I get a warning:

> Possible iteration over unexpected (custom / inherited) members, probably missing hasOwnProperty check

So I get what it's saying, so in that case would it be better to use something like `for (const key of Object.keys(obj))` instead of `for (const key in obj)`?

Are there any real differences between the two, performance-wise?

Comment: what your IDE wants is sanity check you should put in your code `if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {.. your code }`

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004314/why-are-object-keys-and-for-in-different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Object.keys() and for ... in different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004314/why-are-object-keys-and-for-in-different)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a slight difference between looping though the `Object.keys` array and looping using a `for...in` statement, which in the majority of cases would not be noted. `Object.keys(obj)` returns only an array with the own properties of the object, while the `for...in` returns also the keys found in the prototype chain, in order the latter to be done extra check to the prototype of the `obj` is needed and then to the prototype of the prototype and so on and so forth, until the whole prototype chain has been visited. This certainly makes the second approach less efficient than the first, but as I have already mentioned, this difference would be hardly noticed in the majority of cases.

For a more formal approach, as it is stated in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

Comment: Thanks. This explains why my IDE was giving the warning.

Answer (score 5):

You can still use `for(var key in obj){}`. It seems it is expecting is `Object.hasOwnProperty` inside the `for..in` loop

This is because `for..in` will also look in prototype chain & will return true even if the key is in prototype chain.

Whereas `Object.hasOwnProperty` will only return true if key is its `owns` property.

You may do like this

```
for(var key in obj){
 if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
  // rest of code}
}
```

Comment: At this point though, you might as well just use the `Object.keys(obj)` implementation. Since the only thing you're avoiding is prototype keys (which is what Object.keys already does).