# How to get access to object keys using *ngFor without using pipes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am using `*ngFor` to loop through the data and generate a dynamic table. But i only have access to the values of the object not the keys. How do you access the object keys using `*ngFor` WITHOUT USING PIPES

```
export class AppComponent {
  users: {}[] = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'johndoe@example.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'janedoe@example.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'marydoe@example.com'
  }
];
}
```

Comment: you can use Object.keys in your app.component.ts file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446241/for-in-or-for-of-object-keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to access the key of object

```
*ngfor="let user of users; i=index"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to use **`Pipe`** , You could simply get the keys using  **`Object.keys;`** in TS

```
export class App {
  users = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'johndoe@example.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'janedoe@example.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'marydoe@example.com'
  }
];
  getKeys = Object.keys;

}
```

and in template

```
 <div *ngFor="let key of getKeys(users[0])">{{key + ' : ' + users[0][key]}}
```

[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/qg9nHpPzFsmSTLBbxBrS?p=preview)