# Switch with object.keys always return default value

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms

i have a problem with a method, i am trying to get the value of a field errors in Angular forms, and then return a string if there is an error.

```
  public getFieldError(form: FormGroup, field:string):string | null{

    if(!form) return null

    const errors = form.controls[field].errors || {}
    
      for(const key in Object.keys(errors)) {
        console.log(Object.keys(errors))
        switch(key){
          case 'required':
            return 'required error';
          case 'minlength':
            return 'minlength error';
          default:
            return 'hi' 
        }
      
    }

    return null
  }
```

when i test the form, `console.log(Object.keys(errors))` returns ['minlength'], so i think the second case, key == 'minlength' should activate, but it always returns the default value. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: duplicate [Difference between ( for... in ) and ( for... of ) statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285897/difference-between-for-in-and-for-of-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns an array. If you check that array's keys, they will be `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. and not `required` and such.

Either use `for of` instead of `for in` so you iterate over the *values* of that array:

```js
for (const key of Object.keys(errors)) {
```

...or use `for in` but without `Object.keys` so you directly iterate over the keys of your object<sup>1</sup>:

```js
for (const key in errors) {
```

---

<sub>**1:** ...and any inherited properties, but in both cases only enumerable ones. Yes, there is a slight difference between the two options as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43446317/1871033) (`Object.keys` doesn't look at the prototype chain), but it should not be relevant for you, as your object most likely won't have any enumerable properties within ancestors in the prototype chain.</sub>