# ESLint doesn't allow for in

Tags: javascript, eslint, for-in-loop

I have an object

```
currentValues= {hey:1212, git:1212, nmo:12121}
```

and I use for in like this:

```
for (const key in currentValues) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(currentValues, key)) {
        yield put(setCurrentValue(key, currentValues[key]));
    }
}
```

ESLint shows me an error which is saying:

> ESLint: for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array. (no-restricted-syntax

How should I edit my code?

Comment: Try `for(const key of currentValues.keys())` if you only need the keys. You can use `entries` if you need the keys and values.

Comment: @AndrewLi are you talking about `Object.keys()`? If so, it'd stiill be questionable, since iterating through an array with `for ... in` is frowned upon.

Comment: @Pointy I'm using `for...of`?

Comment: Oops sorry, carry on :) But still; there's no `.keys()` function on that object.

Comment: I'm not seeing an array.

Comment: If `for in` was terrible, why can't they deprecate it 

Answer (score 86):

It says,

> Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting
>   array.

So you could do something like this to get the object keys as an array and then loop through the keys to make necessary changes.

```js
currentValues= {hey:1212, git:1212, nmo:12121}

Object.keys(currentValues).forEach(function(key) {
  yield put(setCurrentValue(key, currentValues[key]));
})
```

Comment: yea, but I do not understand why? It could be really a problem?

Comment: How can this be any more intuitive or short than a plain old `for in`?

Comment: @Jonny `for..in` will loop through the whole prototype chain as the ESLint message explains, so you end up getting unexpected items in your loop. To avoid this, people would add an `if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call...)` inside the `for..in` loop (see OP code sample). Using `Object.keys` eliminates the need for this `if` inside `for..in`, it's much cleaner and straightforward than using `for..in`.

Comment: A 'yield' expression is only allowed in a generator body

Answer (score 14):

I used the following:

```
const keys = Object.keys(currentValues);
const values = Object.values(currentValues);
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
    yield put(setCurrentValue(keys[i], values[i]));
}
```

This is correct and without ESLint errors.

Answer (score 6):

I would do it by refactoring, in the following ways.

```
const currentValues = { hey: 1212, git: 1212, nmo: 12121 };

Object.keys(currentValues).forEach((e) => console.log(`${e} : ${currentValues[e]}`));
```

**Results:**

hey : 1212
git : 1212
nmo : 12121

```
Object.values(currentValues).forEach((e) => console.log(`Values: ${e}`));
```

**Results:**

(2)Values: 1212
Values: 12121

```
Object.entries(currentValues).forEach((e) => console.log(`${e[0]} : ${e[1]}`));
```

**Results:**

hey : 1212
git : 1212
nmo : 12121

Answer (score 4):

You can get the array of all your values inside your object just doing

```
var myValuesInArray = Object.values(currentValues);
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
let animal = {
  eats: "Eating",
};
let rabbit = {
  jumps: "Jumping",
};

rabbit.__proto__ = animal;

for (const rabbitProps in rabbit) {
  // This will print both eats and jumps properties because they're part of
  // prototype chain
  console.log("rabbitProps: ", rabbitProps);
}

// This prints only jumps as Object.keys shows only the keys of object
console.log(Object.keys(rabbit));
```

Checking out the above code you can see that when using for...in loop[ it will show all the properties that are part of object as well as properties set in the prototype chain of the object and so eslint suggests to use Object.keys or value or entries, as they do not look into prototype chain instead they just look at your object.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is similar to the above, but here is a full example:

```
const data = res.data;
const keys = Object.keys(data);
const values = Object.values(data);

for (let i = 0; i <= keys.length; i += 1) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(values, i)) {
     this.rows.push({
        name: values[i].name,
        email: values[i].email,
        address: values[i].address,
        phone: values[i].phone,
        role: values[i].role,
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is not required if using `Object.keys()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004314/why-are-object-keys-and-for-in-different

Answer (score 2):

try this instead:

```
Object.keys(currentValues).map(key => (yield put(setCurrentValue(key, currentValues[key]))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for...in` will iterate over all properties including those from Object prototype. I am not sure why you are doing `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(currentValues, key)` 
instead of just:
`currentValues.hasOwnProperty(key)`.
I think this should make ESLint aware that you are filtering for own properties only.

However, I suggest using `for (const key of Object.keys())`, which is more semantic.

Comment: using `hasOwnPrototype(..)` from `Object` is better. see http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins